# Closed form of the sum of two binomial expansions

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-theorem

I would like to know if there is a simple closed form for the following expression:

$(x+y)^n + (x+z)^n$

Expanding the above I get

$(y^n + z^n) + nx(y^{n-1}+z^{n-1}) + \frac{(n-1)n}{2}x^2(y^{n-2} + z^{n-2}) + \mathcal{O}(x^3) $,

but it isn't clear to me if this can factor into something of the form $(x+w)^n + u$ where $w$ and $u$ depend on $y$ and $z$ (in general I mean, it is fairly easy to get something of this form for $n=1$ or $n=2$).

Comment: Are you trying to write $(x+y)^n + (y+z)^n = (x+w)^n$ and find what $w$ is? You should be able to solve this for $w$ (and find that it depends on $x$ in general).

Comment: Fermat's Last Theorem has implications for your closed form.

Comment: I changed the closed form requirement to $(x+w)^n + u$ in light of your comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for a symmetric formulation like this
$$
\eqalign{
  & \left( {x + y} \right)^{\,n}  + \left( {x + z} \right)^{\,n}  =   \cr 
  &  = \left( {x + \left( {{{z + y} \over 2}} \right) - \left( {{{z - y} \over 2}} \right)} \right)^{\,n}
  + \left( {x + \left( {{{z + y} \over 2}} \right) + \left( {{{z - y} \over 2}} \right)} \right)^{\,n}  =   \cr 
  &  = \left( {x + \left( {{{z + y} \over 2}} \right)} \right)^{\,n}
 \left( {\left( {1 - \left( {{{z - y} \over {2x + y + z}}} \right)} \right)^{\,n}  + \left( {1 + \left( {{{z - y} \over {2x + y + z}}} \right)} \right)^{\,n} } \right) \cr} 
$$